# Midlet generate code

Tags: java, midlet

I have project and want to add some elements by Visual Midlet tabs: Screen, Flow, but fail.

Editor don't generate new code and don't add my elements. I can't change it manually(editor area), but can write only in special area: // write post-action user code here etc.

What I must do for creating menu and forms by visual tools?

Comment: What do you have so far? Show some code.

Comment: Code was generated by editor on other computer by its owner, but I cant change it and cant show you code,sorry. Maybe there is some trigger that say to editor:"Generate it again with new corrections"?